# Control xml attributes

Tags: layout, admob

Hello I have a problem wich I would like to find the perfect solution for it.

I am a publisher in many monetizing platforms like : admob,adfonic..

for example in my main layout.

I declared admob but if I wanna show adfonic I must do a whole update of my app vercion for my users would see adfonic instead.

So is there anyway of control those lines or controling that xml that shows either admob of adfonic ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a mediation solution like Admob mediation where you can configure which networks to use at runtime.